# Avoiding regex match variable being reused

Tags: perl

Basically, I'm looping through html files and looking for a couple of regexes. They match which is fine, but I don't expect every file to contain matches, but when the loop runs, every iteration contains the same match (despite it not being in that file). I assume that by using $1 it is persisting through each iteration.

I've tried using an arbitary regex straight after each real match to reset it, but that doesn't seem to work. The thread I got that idea from seemed to have a lot of argument etc on best practice and the original questions problem, so I thought it would be worth asking for specific advice to my code. It's likely not written in a great way either:

```
# array of diff filenames
opendir(TDIR, "$folder/diff/$today") || die "can't opendir $today: $!";
@diffList = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir(TDIR);
closedir TDIR;

# List of diff files
print "List of Diff files:\n" . join("\n", @diffList) . "\n\n";

for($counter = 0; $counter < scalar(@diffList); $counter++) {
    # Open diff file, read in to string
    $filename = $diffList[$counter];
    open FILE, "<", "$folder/diff/$today/$filename";
    while(<FILE>)   {
        $lines .= $_;
    }
    close FILE or warn "$0: close today/$filename: $!";

    # Use regular expressions to extract the found differences
    if($lines =~ m/$plus1(.*?)$span/s) {
        $plus = $1;
        "a" =~ m/a/;
    } else {$plus = "0";}
    if($lines =~ m/$minus1(.*?)$span/s) {
        $minus = $1;
        "a" =~ m/.*/;
    } else {$minus = "0";}

    # If changes were found, send them to the database
    if($plus ne "0" && $minus ne "0") {
        # Do stuff
    }
    $plus = "0";
    $minus = "0";
}
```

If I put a print inside the "do stuff" if, it's always true and always shows the same two values that are found in one of the files.
Hopefully I've explained my situation well enough. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show us the loop? The code you've posted seems fine after a cursory glance...

Comment: Sure thing - let me add more information

Comment: Basically get a list of file names from a directory in to an array, loop over that array and open each file one by one. check for two certain regexes. if both are successful matches i want to send them to a database (that step is fine). every step of the loop gets to the database if with the same matches (that I know are only in 1 file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your code appends lines from newly-read files onto `$lines`. Have you tried explicitly clearing it after each iteration?

Comment: No, I hadn't considered it might be that part that was causing the issue. Perhaps it's only using the first file it finds each time (keeping the contents).

Comment: Adding $lines = "" at the bottom of the loop seems to have had a positive effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's already been answered, but you could also consider a different syntax for reading the file. It can be noticeably quicker and helps you avoid little bugs like this.

Just add this to read the file between the open/close:

```
local $/ = undef;
$lines = <FILE>;
```

That'll temporarily unset the line separator so it reads the whole file at once. Just enclose it in a { } block if you need to read another file in the same scope.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the tip - I'll be sure to keep in mind in future.